# Calculate data and passing to Theme

Tags: theme-development

i try to develope a Theme for displaying the Data of my own Plugin.

Now I have the following scenario:

- I'm getting the PostId over get_the_ID(); (e.g. PostType = 'Product')
- then I'm getting Data from the Database. e.g.  Productprices, ProductTaxes, Discounts, Campaigns etc.
- Now I want to calculate the actual Price for the Product

And now I want to display all the Data I was getting from the database and all calculated data.

At this time, I have all the code I need for getting the data above in my single-product.php-File.
But I know that this is not a good solution.
Because when I create another theme and want to change the style my product data are displayed, the calculate-Methods stays the same.

So my question is, how should I calculate my data and passing the values to my single-product.php-File, so that the only task of the single-product.php is to display these data?

Comment: You can have a look at this [article](https://pippinsplugins.com/template-file-loaders-plugins/), it can provide a solution on how to load template from plugn, but you can also do that using a shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I had already used a template_loader. But In the comments of your article I found my answer :-)
I'm passing my variables I want to use in the template file to an array, and bevore I include the founded template file I call the extract method. So I can use the variables in the template without to do the calculate methods in it :-)

Comment: Nice you got an answer. Better answer your own question with some example code, so that someone with similar issue can get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. See this [article](https://pippinsplugins.com/template-file-loaders-plugins/) (postet by Mayeenul Islam in the comments of my question Post) to get an understanding of template_loader.

If you understand then, how you locate a template, you can write one small methode to pass parameters to this template.

I wrote the following method:

```
    public static function get_my_template( $template_name, $args = array(), $template_path = '', $default_path = '' ) {
        if ( $args && is_array( $args ) ) {
            extract( $args );
        }

        $located = self::locate_template( $template_name, $template_path, $default_path );

        include( $located );
}
```

as you can see, in this method you are able to pass $args as parameter.
The function "extract", extracts the array so that every key is his own variable. ([See the manual for more information](http://php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php))

But this was not my idea!
Someone in the comments of the article write this suggestion.
And when you look at the code of [woocommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) you will see that they doing the same way.